# Problem reading and getting data of the excel file of larger size 50MB to 1GB using sheetjs (xlsx.js)?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs

Problem reading and getting data of the excel file of larger size 50MB to 1GB using sheetjs (xlsx.js)?

We have use case to upload a large file size and read its contents to get the sheet data. We are using javascript library xlsx.js to parse the file. But while uploading a file size more than 50mb, the xlsx library gets stuck on the reading operation of the file and the page becomes unresponsive. Below is the line of code where it gets stuck and couldn't proceed further.

const workbook = XLSX.read(data, opts);

We have tried to slice the sheet data and then read the file again but didn't receive any luck.
Is there any solution that will support the large file upload using xlsx library?

Comment: What are `opts`? Is there some option related to splitting in chunks?